# Why sun 'set' and not sun 'sat'?

Tags: grammar

I know that grammatically "I sat on the couch", or "I set the cup on the table".
I know that if you are doing the action yourself then it is 'sat'. Why doesn't this apply to the sun? The sun is doing the action

So couldn't you say "I watched the sun sat" rather than "I watched the sun set?
Maybe there is a simple answer.

I mean really, the sun doesn't do either right? The sun doesn't move. If anything the earth is what does all the moving.    Thanks

Comment: The fact that the Sun only appears to set is a non-issue. There are lots of examples of English phrases that are not meant as literal scientific assertions.

Comment: I think you've just discovered one of the many edge cases in English where the rules are broken. This usually happens with older phrases. I've not put this as an answer, as someone else may offer a better explanation.

Comment: Note that even if we are specifically talking about the sun sitting down, we would say "I watched the sun **sit**", not "**sat**".

Comment: @FumbleFingers ?? What? Of course sit and set are cognate. They're just variants of the same root. How do they have 'no connection whatsoever'?

Comment: @Mitch: What can I say? Under the "etymology" for **sit** the OED says *Common Germanic: Old English **sittan** (sæt, sǽton, geseten), = Old Frisian **sitta***, and for **set** they have *Common Germanic: Old English **sęttan** = Old Frisian **setta***. If you know that Old Frisian ***sitta*** and ***setta*** are cognate then fine, but this hardly relates to them as *English* words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They are causative pairs dating from PIE, like *lie/lay* and *rise/raise*. The vowel change indicates causation, like *drink/drench*. *Sit/set* are identical: the causative one causes something else to become in the state indicated by the non-causative.

Comment: @tchrist: I did vaguely know that once, but had forgotten. Actually, I suppose it *could* be useful to a learner to be aware of that "causative" background. But it's still an ELL question, imho. I also seem to recall that ***set*** takes up more dictionary space than any other English word - which would only get worse if they included ***sit*** as a subheading within that section.

Comment: It was a revelation to me when I realised that _set_ is a causitive of _sit_, because in my dialect (BrE) _set_ barely has that meaning. It can mean "place something purposefully in a specific place or configuration", but I would never say "Set it down here" - I'd say "put it down here".

Answer (score 4):

The sun does *set* if we use this common definition for *set*:

> a :  to pass below the horizon :  go down * the sun sets
>
> b :  to come to an end [[link]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set)

...but it doesn't *set* something down, or *sit* on the horizon.  It's a different definition entirely.

The Oxford English Dictionary has an [entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176793?rskey=1m3tyF&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) on this use of "set."  Look under "Etymology" for available detail.  I would say that except for recent changes in language, the information you want will be in OED or good luck finding it anywhere.

Comment: I assume this confusion is arising because of this US English definition of 'set'  *to cause to sit :  place in or on a seat* (per Merriam Webster, which I'm not aware of in british English.

Comment: @Spagirl That is in fact the original, most basic meaning of the word, a causative of _sit_.

Comment: I think the sun can too sit on the horizon, at least in elevated or poetic language. And in vernacular language we certainly say that the sun sits low in the sky.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple definitions for set.  A whole set of definitions, actually.
I believe you may be incorrectly assuming the above sentence refers to the primary definition of "put, lay, or stand (something) in a specified place or position."

If you use the definition "to bring into a specified state," it makes more sense.

Also:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set

**Scroll down to transitive verb, definition**

6 a :  to pass below the horizon :  go down. *the sun sets*

Comment: There *are* multiple definitions of "set". The OED entry for "set" (including quotations) is about 50000 words long, longer than some novels.

Answer (score 0):

***Set*** is used to describe the movement of the sun or other luminary.  It means to go down; to make an apparent descent towards and below the horizon. (OED)

At the end of the day you can *watch the sun **set*** / *watch as the sun **sets***.

Or, if you did this yesterday, you can say -

*I watched the sun **set*** / *watched as the sun **set***,  (past tense (and past participle) of *set* is *set*).

> 1816   Scott Black Dwarf vi, in Tales of my Landlord 1st Ser. I. 119   The sun setting red.
>
> 1823   F. D. Hemans Siege Valencia i. 121   Till the last pale star had set.
>
> 1847   C. Brontë Jane Eyre I. v. 68   The moon was set, and it was very dark.

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason you can't say **I saw the sun sat**: that is not how we conjugate a sentence like that.

Let's take another verb as an example: *to eat*.  We would say

> He eats.
> He ate.
> I see him eat.
> I saw him eat.

Note that *eat* never gets conjugated in the second pair of sentences!  It is always the bare infinitive.  Only the main verb is conjugated.  Since the verb that the sun is performing is *to set*, it can only be "watched the sun *set*".

Comment: But the verb "set" is used indicatively too, with "sun" as the subject - eg. *The sun set beneath the horizon* or in the present tense *The sun sets at 8.04pm today*.